# How to access Secret Manager secrets with ECS task?

Tags: amazon-ecs, aws-secrets-manager, ecs-taskdefinition

Im using ECS with Fargate and trying to access my Secret Manager secrets, but when I spin up my task, they just arent there.

Since the secret is a list of secret variables, will it be evaluated as if it was a .env file?
What I'm missing ?

Im trying this way:

Im my task definition container: (My secret name has a slash "/")

```
"secrets": [{
    "name": "ecs-fretegestao/main-api",
    "valueFrom": "arn:aws:secretsmanager:<my-region>:<my-acc>:secret:ecs-fretegestao/main-api-4qTFqP"
}]
```

My vpc and subnets have the secretsmanager endpoint:

```
com.amazonaws.us-east-1.secretsmanager
```

And my task execution role has access to everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Since the secret is a list of secret variables, will it be evaluated as if it was a .env file? What I'm missing ?

No, it won't be evaluated at all. It's unclear what you are expecting it to do here.

This: `"name": "ecs-fretegestao/main-api",` tells ECS to create an environment variable inside the container named `ecs-fretegestao/main-api` (it's really weird to have a `/` in an environment variable name by the way). That environment variable will have the value of the secret in it. The secret value will be whatever this ARN identifies: `arn:aws:secretsmanager:<my-region>:<my-acc>:secret:ecs-fretegestao/main-api-4qTFqP`. If that ARN identifies a list, then the environment variable will contain a list.

Comment: Hey, you again! Thx for the answer. I figured that out. I thought the list would work as a .env file, but I do need to get the varaibles programatically, so Im using env file from s3 now.